# Selenium webdriver not logging into live.com

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been attempting to login to live.com with the Selenium Webdriver however every attempt results in an invalid email or password. A correct login is used. I tested it in a physical browser. I'm uncertain if this is the case but I believe sendkeys is not working. Code below.

```
protected static Map<String,String> settings = new HashMap<String,String>();
public static WebDriver pwb;
```

In Main:

```
    // Default settings
    settings.put("browser","chrome");
    settings.put("os","WINDOWS8");


    // Sort arguments and put into HashMap
    grab(args);

    // Set browser settings
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnitWithJs();
    cap.setBrowserName(settings.get("browser"));
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.extractFromSysProperty(settings.get("os")));
    d.log(cap.asMap().toString());

    // Create web browser object
    pwb = new HtmlUnitDriver(cap);

    login();
```

In login():

```
Load("http://login.live.com",0); // custom load function
d.log(pwb.getTitle());
if(pwb.getTitle().contains("Sign in to your")){ // Full login
            d.log("Executing full login.\nEmail:" + settings.get("email") + "\nPassword:"+settings.get("password"));
//              if (pwb instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
//                  ((JavascriptExecutor) pwb).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('login')[0].click();"); //value = " + settings.get("email") + "");
//                  ((JavascriptExecutor) pwb).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('passwd')[0].click();"); //.value = " + settings.get("password") + "");
//              }
            // TODO get login working
            pwb.findElement(By.id("i0116")).clear();
            pwb.findElement(By.id("i0116")).sendKeys(settings.get("email"));
            pwb.findElement(By.id("i0118")).clear();
            pwb.findElement(By.id("i0118")).sendKeys(settings.get("password"));
            pwb.findElement(By.name("SI")).click();
            // Attempted = true;
        }
```

If anymore information is needed please let me know.

Comment: not sure,I have tried the same with firefox browser and is working fine. Can u test ur code by replacing HtmlUnitDriver with any other browser??

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does work with other drivers but I was hoping to get an invisible driver option. I suppose I can't get that and log in too.